# applying a class to specific li not sub of it

Tags: html, css

I have a `li` that it has subs of `li`'s :

```
  <li class="active"><a href="">Main Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

when my apply `active` class to first `li`, all sub of `li`'s will change.
I want to apply this class just first `li`. how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the styles of all the `<li>` which are children of `li.active` with the following syntax:

```
li.active li {

[... STYLES HERE...]

}
```

If you want to apply styles to `li.active` which don't apply to the children you can declare the styles for `li.active` and then re-declare any inherited styles (which you don't want inherited) for `li.active li`:

```
li.active {

[... STYLES HERE...]

}

li.active li {

[... STYLES HERE...]

}
```

Comment: This answer is just wrong - the OP says specifically ONLY the first LI

Comment: Aha... I maybe misunderstood the question. It's not written in the clearest English. (I understand the OP is a non-native English speaker - so this isn't a criticism, simply an acknowledgement). I read the question as: _When I apply the `.active` class to the first `li`, I want the styles of all the child `li`s to change. I don't want to have to apply the `.active` class to all the `li`s. I want to apply this class just to the first `li`._